# Will I have to level my profession up to the current max for Battle for Azeroth?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I recently used my boost and have a new character in World of Warcraft. In the upcoming expansion, I want to be able to use the alchemy/herblism that I have, but they are at level 1.

In the classic worlds you are able to gather from any herb at any level, will this also apply in Battle for Azeroth?

Comment: @Frank The pre-patch has already gone live with profession changes.

Comment: I withdraw the close vote, then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of patch 8.0.1 released on July 17, 2018 each expansion now has its own profession levels.

- Classic goes from 1 to 300
- Burning Crusade goes from 1 to 75
- Wrath of the Lich King goes from 1 to 75
- Cataclysm from 1 to 75
- Mists of Pandaria goes from 1 to 75
- Warlords of Draenor goes from 1 to 100
- Legion goes from 1 to 100
- Battle for Azeroth (Kul Tiras or Zandalari depending on faction) goes from 1 to 150

This means you no longer have to level professions in older expansions to use them in newer content.

Archaeology is the exception to this rule and instead goes to 950.  In addition, Archaeology digsites follow some additional rules:

- New digsites are assigned based on your current level and the pre-7.3.5 zone levels.
- Outlands digsites require 300 skill.
- Wrath of the Lich King digsites require 375 skill.
- Cataclysm digsites require 450 skill.
- Mists of Pandaria digsites require 525 skill.
- All other expansions always have their digsites available.
- All expansions other than Legion and Battle for Azeroth have 4 digsites available per continent at any one time.

  - Legion only has 3 digsites available and they are all in the same zone.  These zones rotate every 2 weeks.
  - Legion's rare solves are done via quests and only one quest is available every 2 weeks.
  - Kul Tiras and Zandalar each have 3 digsites in each of their 3 zones available at all times.

Comment: Archaeology is apparently the only exception to this rule.

Comment: A nice addition: If you had a profession skilled up prior to the pre-patch you get to keep your skill points. So a Legion Master (800) will have all old expansions leveled up already, a Dreanor Master (700) up to WoD and so on... you keep everything up to the level you had when the patch went live.

Comment: With the removal of the First Aid profession, if you knew the recipes for First Aid and have the profession they got moved to, you'll already know them.  For example, bandages moved to Tailoring while antidotes and salves moved to Alchemy.